# Suggested edits in top-bar put flags over the winterbash snowflake

Tags: bug, top-bar

Suggested edits in the top bar put the flag count right over the winterbash snowflake. Looks pretty ugly if you ask me...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Sorry, `status-nonrepro` here.

Comment: Ah, the problems of the ruling class.

Comment: And some people wanted to add meta and chat links back to the bar.

Comment: @AmalMurali: Probably because your top bar doesn't need space for that shiny diamond ;)